# Springboot JPA map object with extra attribute to a non entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'd like to have a field in my Entity which is not persistent (I don't want to have a column for it in the database), because the values for it will be dependent on the current request. This field will store the distance of the Entity's location from a given arbitrary location. I'd like to filter the results by the maximum distance to list in the results so the values of this distance field should be calculated during the request.

My problem is that, by using the `@Transient` annotation I can make the column to be ignored by the database, so it won't we created, but the annotation makes the JPA to ignore the field completely so my native query cannot fill the field with the calculated value. (the filtering work in the request and I'm using POSTGRESQL)

```
@Query(value = " SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * , ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?1) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?2) ) + sin( radians(?1) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM health_center GROUP BY id) ss WHERE distance < ?3 ORDER BY distance LIMIT ?4", nativeQuery = true)
    List<HealthCenter> findByWithinRange(Float latitude, Float longitude, Integer distance, Integer limit);
```

Comment: Have you considered "experimenting" with `@Column(updatable = false, insertable = false, ...)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it doesn't work.